# How to overwrite a file in sdcard in android?

Tags: android

I need to read a file in the sd card in my android device and write the contents of this file into another file in the sd card which is already existing.

Here is my code to read a file anywhere in the sdcard.

```
public String readFromFile(String fileName) {

    String ret = "";
    try {

        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        //Get the text file
        File file = new File(sdcard, fileName);


        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        if ( bufferedReader != null ) {


            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Can some one please tell me how can I copy the contents of this file into another file on sdcard after reading.

I do not wish to append but to overwrite the contents of the file.

I need a method in this format

```
void writeFile(String fileName, String Data){

//code to overwite with given data

}
```

Can someone please help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
void writeFile(String fileName, String data) {
     File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName);
     FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile, false);
     byte[] contents = data.getBytes();
     out.write(contents);
     out.flush();
     out.close();
}
```

The most important part is the `false` in the FileOutputStream constructor. The second parameter is `append`. If set to false, the file will be overwritten if it exists.

Comment: the code compiles well. But I get a java.lang.NullPointerException. I am calling the method like this. writeFile("abc.txt", data). abc.txt is present in the sdcard. Still it fails to find the file. Could you please help.

Comment: Did you request the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission? I updated my code to include the SD-Card path.

Comment: It works now, after the code edit to include the SD-Card path. Thank you :)